# How to execute a function when mouse overs a division and all its nesting elements inside?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

How to execute a function when mouse overs a division and all its nesting elements inside? Like

```
<div id="main">
      <div id="sub1">Sometext</div>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
   $("#main").mouseover(function() {
      //This function fails to execute  if i am over #sub1
   });
});
</script>
```

I want to execute the mouseover function when it with over `#main` regardless of the children inside

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at Moin's answer first, but if you still need to handle it with jQuery...

The following will trigger for all elements under #main including #main.  I would add a check to see if the code has already been run or is running before triggering it again.

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $("#main, #main *").mouseover(function(e) {
       // This will trigger for all elements under #main, be careful
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work. I would check your CSS to see that `sub1` is not being positioned or floated such that `main` fails to wrap it.

also try the jQuery `mouseenter` method.